# Running loop in excel vba 2016 for changing series in charts

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro and I wish to loop the following program for 500 charts starting from 1.

```
Sub Arrow()
'
' Arrow Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 459").Activate

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 2.5
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLengthMedium
        .EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWide
    End With
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 2.5
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLengthMedium
        .EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWide
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that "please tell me *urgently*" is going to have quite the opposite effect of what you hope.

Comment: The first thing you will want to do is remove all `.Select`, `.Activate` and `Selection` commands and references in place of indexed based direct references. Once you have that, a `For i = 1 to .Count` will be easy. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jeeped. What you want is not difficult. However, moving from `Select` etc to Index based takes some learning.

the code below should do what you want. It worked for me in Office 2010, which uses  `SeriesCollection(1)` instead of `FullSeriesCollection(1)`

```
Sub Arrow() ' ' Arrow Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q ' ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 459").Activate

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cht As Chart

    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Count

        Set cht = ActiveWorkbook.Charts(i)

        With cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Weight = 2.5
            .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
            .EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLengthMedium
            .EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWide
        End With

        With cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
            .Transparency = 0
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 2.5
            .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
            .EndArrowheadLength = msoArrowheadLengthMedium
            .EndArrowheadWidth = msoArrowheadWide
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Now you know how to use a `For` Loop and Index based references.